# Firestore Security Rules read count on get() document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have to check a document value != a string value in the Firebase Security rules.
So I have to first check if the document exists and then check the value.

```
allow read: !get(path).data || get(path).data.value !== 'xyz';
```

As I am calling the `get()` method twice, will it count 2 reads? If yes, how can I write the logic so that I fetch the document data once and reuse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#firestore-rules), you are only charged once.

> You are only charged one read per dependent document even if your rules refer to that document more than once.

Comment: Thank you! @ Dharmaraj